# How to make the SQL query type "Update if exist, else insert"

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

There is first the result of the selection from the table provided `"IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID" = 300857`

[image]

There is a second result set from the table with the condition `"IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID" = 589248`

[image]

How to append those records for which no second sample records from the first sample and update the entries in the second sample, the first field in the second sample `IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID` leave equal `589248`.

Comment: Did you try REPLACE? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html

Comment: please help to write a query

Comment: I suspect that `insert . . . on duplicate key update` does exactly what you want.  However, I can't figure out exactly what you want.  Which table is being updated?  What columns define two rows as being the same?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want, I think you should use :

replace into synthax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/replace.html

Hope it helps